# Is there a simple way to plot mutiples lines in R with plotly (Comparaison with plotly in python)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Hello everyone here is my issue:

In python, I can easily do a multiple-line plot from my raw data in one line using plotly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

#generating the data 
I=np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
data={'0 min':np.cos(I)*0.5,
'10 min':np.cos(I)*1,
'20 min':np.cos(I)*2,
'30 min':np.cos(I)*4}
I=np.linspace(250, 349, 100)
df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=I)# df of my raw data

px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns)
```

However, in R, with the same data :

```
library(plotly)
I<-seq(0, 10, length.out=100)
df = data.frame(t0min=cos(I)*0.5,
                t10min=cos(I)*1,
                t20min= cos(I)*2,
                t30min=cos(I)*4)
I<-seq(250, 349, length.out=100)
rownames(df)<-I
```

this does not work:

```
plot_ly(df, 
        x = rownames(df),
        y = colnames(df),
        name = ~colnames(df),
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines')#does not work
```

The only solution that I found is to reshape my data frame entirely :

```
name=vector()
x=vector()
Y=vector()
for (i in colnames(df)){
name=c(name,rep(i,length(df[,i])) )
x=c(x, rownames(df[i]))
Y=c(Y,  df[,i])
}
DF=data.frame(x, Y, name)

plot_ly(DF, 
       x = ~x,
       y = ~Y,
       color = ~name,
       name = ~name,
       type = 'scatter',
       mode = 'lines')
```

Is there a simple solution to achieve the same result in R without reshaping the entire data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't. But you could simplify the reshaping of your data considerably by using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Also, instead of adding your `I` column as row names (which TBMK is different from the pandas concept of an index column) add it as a column to your dataset:

```r
library(plotly)

I <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(
  t0min = cos(I) * 0.5,
  t10min = cos(I) * 1,
  t20min = cos(I) * 2,
  t30min = cos(I) * 4
)
df$I <- I

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-I) %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~I,
    y = ~value,
    name = ~name,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines"
  )
```

[image]